# BroadcastReceiver with intent-filter for them?

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

Her is what I'm trying to accomplish:

1. When user tries to share some text from any app (Like sharing a tweet or a link), my app will appear in the sharing list.
2. If he select my app, some simple code will be run (like showing a Toast) then that's it. No interface or UI is needed.

Here is how I did it:

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<receiver 
android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver" >
    <intent-filter
        android:label="select my app">
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:mimeType="text/plain" />
    </intent-filter>                
</receiver>
```

**MyBroadcastReceiver.java**

```
public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //Some simple code
    Toast.makeText(arg0, "My Receiver is cool", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

This didn't work, my app doesn't show in the sharing list.

**Why I work with `BroadcatReceivers` and not with `Activities`?** Because I don't want any UI and I think that is why we have receivers (correct my plz)

Am I doing it right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> This didn't work, my app doesn't show in the sharing list.

`ACTION_SEND` is used with activities. You are attempting to use a `BroadcastReceiver`. Since a `BroadcastReceiver` is not an activity, this will not work.

> Am I doing it right?

No.

> If he select my app, some simple code will be run (like showing a Toast) then that's it. No interface or UI is needed.

You still need an activity. However, if you give the activity `Theme.NoDisplay`, and you do not call `setContentView()`, there will be no UI for the activity. Usually, you just call `finish()` from `onCreate()` after doing whatever it is you wanted to do (in this case, display a `Toast`).

For example, [this sample application](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/Intents/FauxSender) shows an activity (`FauxSender`) set up to do precisely what you want: respond to `ACTION_SEND` with a `Toast`. It has another activity that issues an `ACTION_SEND` so you can see the results.